# How to retrieve multiple lines when one condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

All i want to do is retrieve all lines associated to a particular sale when a condition is met.

So I may have 5 lines on an order, I'm trying to pull back all 5 lines where one of the lines has say a certain product code.

The lines I'm trying to retrieve have the same orderid, and diffe

As you can see the orderid is the same for both lines and I want to retrieve both lines where the ManualCode is equal to 'STKCORRECTION'

Simple eh ?

Comment: Can you provide any sort of schema information, or what you've tried already? Without this, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Seems like some of the question has got lost in the middle there. Please edit and complete.

Answer (score 2):

You leave out many important details but I'll take a stab at this.  Say you have the following table:

```
OrderItemId   | Code   | OrderId
---------------------------------
1               red      2 
2               black    2
3               green    2
4               green    3
5               blue     3
```

and you wanted to select all OrderItems where one of the OrderItems in the order had code `red`, you could use the following query:

```
with reds as
(
    SELECT distinct OrderId FROM OrderItems WHERE Code = 'red'
)
SELECT * FROM OrderItems as oi
INNER JOIN reds as r
ON oi.OrderId = r.OrderId
```

This would return the first three OrderItems in the sample table.